# Protect DLL from use in other projects other than my own

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I'm going to build a large project and want to create several libraries (DLL) for it. I don't want to merge them all in one EXE, but want to use seperate DLL files.

I don't want those DLL's to be used by others, so these DLL's should be protected so that they can only be used in my own project.

I was thinking of using some sort of password in the New() proc, but that doesn't work for shared classes.

Other solution I was thinking of: is it possible to check if the calling assembly has the same strong name as the DLL?

These solutions are just one of my ideas. I don't know if those will work and am not saying that one of them is the way to go.

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

BTW: I also use a obfuscator to protect my code.

Comment: Write a web app instead.

Comment: Not really a solution, do you think?

Comment: Well of course it is, nobody can get to your DLL.  As long as you are convinced that you cannot trust your customers and cannot obligate them with a license agreement then it is by far the best solution.

Comment: I continue to disagree. Whether an application should be WinForm or WebApp is not part of the discussion/question. The application is and will stay a WinForm application. I know how to protect a DLL by merge it in the parent assembly (EXE) but am just asking if it's possible to protect it as a separate DLL file. It's not that I don't trust my customers by default.

Comment: Strong names won't be the same between two components, because they have different assembly names.  Ultimately this is a very difficult problem to solve, and the specific reason you're trying to solve it will shape the solution - so I'd ask "why don't you want anyone else to use your DLL?"  Because the algorithm is proprietary, because it controls access to a secure resource, or some other reason?

Comment: @Dan: I don't want to be used by others for several reasons, like the one you mention (security, proprietary). If there's no simple/good way to protect them, then I will just choose to embed them in the EXE.

Comment: @Marc V: even embedding in the .exe doesn't necessarily stop people from reusing/copying the functionality.  You need to be very clear what your requirements are before choosing a security-related solution, else you risk choosing something that doesn't solve the right problem.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look in to [System.ComponentModel.LicenseProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe8b1eh9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). You can use whatever authentication method you want for checking to see if they have a valid copy of the dll.

Comment: I was looking for something more simple. Is it f.e. possible to check if the calling assembly has the same strong name as the DLL?

Comment: @marc why did you ask the question the way you did? You should have simply asked about stro names since you've decided that's the solution already.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I think you misunderstood the intentions of my question; sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I don't think that the strong names approach will work or is the best solution. I just mentioned it as it's one of my ideas of approaching the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim E.dll.Com.proc.ecription.pass = "0.0.13",bit
If user.intrude.falsepasscode then
process.break (intrude,process)
Use.facilitator 0.492
End if
If 029302 = 029302 Then
Returnt.kill.me.process
msgbox("Var dll cannot be used because its protected for sole use in VBEXplor.exe")
```

Paste this code into the dll while in code edit, and it should work!

Comment: No linz Etter its dim V.dll not E.dll!

Comment: What the heck is this code? And what's with your comment apparently commenting to yourself?